# Anti-commutator in Quantization of Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization, spin-statistics, anticommutator

Can anyone explain while calculating $\left \{ \Psi, \Psi^\dagger \right \} $, set of equation 5.4 in david tong notes lead us to
$$Σ_s Σ_r [b_p^s u^s(p)e^{ipx} b_q^r†u^r†(q)e^{-iqy}+ b_q^r †u^r†(q)e^{-iqy} b_p^s u^s(p)e^{ipx}].$$

My question is how the above mentioned terms can be written as 
$$Σ_sΣ_r[ \{b_p^s, b_q^r †\} u^s(p)u^r†(q)e^{i.(p.x-q.y)}]$$.And why not
 $$Σ_sΣ_r[ \{b_p^s, b_q^r †\} u^r†(q)u^s(p)e^{i.(p.x-q.y)}]$$
As per my knowledge $$u^s(p)u^r†(q)!= u^r†(q)  u^s(p)$$
please see equation 5.6 in david tong notes. $s$ and $r$ are spinor index and summed over 1-2.

[image]

Please consider the calculation for fermionic quantization, the image i have uploaded for reference only.

Comment: Use some formula editing. This is unreadable.

Comment: Already edited. Please check.

Comment: The ordering of spinors is very important.... $u^s(p)u^{r†} (q)$ is per definition a matrix (it is the so called dyadic product, which is a special case of the Kronecker product...or in physics sloppy style: a column vector times a row vector is a matrix), while $u^{r†} (q)  u^s(p)$ is a scalar....